# How to introduce scroll in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

The SVG elements like rect,img are placed inside svg tag. Dynamically i am placing foreign object inside svg tag. The size of foreign object is greater then the svg element size. how can i introduce a scroll in svg so that the foregin object would be visible to user.

Comment: I have used overflow attribute for svg tag, even then the scroll is not coming.
I am using like,
var svg = d3.select("#myDivID")
                    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("overflow","auto");

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the overflow property of the element's style:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflow.asp